# render multiple charts using a loop ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, charts, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 15 charts that have the same name & number of labels, and same data types. So instead of creating 15 charts code I want to loop through a list of charts, and render them dynamically.

In my ViewModel I have:

```
        public List<Chart> ChartsList { get; set; }
```

which contains a list of an object Analytics:

```
        public List<ObjectAnalytic> Analytic { get; set; }

        public class ObjectAnalytic
        {
            public string Name { get; set; } //for labels
            public int Count { get; set; }
        }
```

In the Action:

```
        ChartList.Add(new Chart
        {
            Analytic = await GetObjectAAnalytic(_db),
        });

        ChartList.Add(new Chart
        {
            Analytic = await GetObjectBAnalytic(_db),
        });
```

The view:

```
                            <div class="row">
                            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ChartsList.Count; i++)
                            {
                                @if (Model.ChartsList[i].Analytic != null && Model.ChartsList[i].Analytic?.Count != 0)
                                {
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-header">
                                                <h4 class="card-title font-small-3">Title</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-content">
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                    <br />
                                                    @*something like this*@
                                                    <div id="pie-chart+@i+_Coverage" class="d-flex justify-content-center"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                }
                            }
                        </div>
```

Finally, rendering the charts where I'm struggling:

```
<script src="~/app-assets/vendors/js/charts/apexcharts.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var $primary = '#5A8DEE',
        $success = '#39DA8A',
        $danger = '#FF5B5C',
        $warning = '#FDAC41',
        $info = '#00CFDD',
        $label_color_light = '#E6EAEE';

    var themeColors = [$primary, $warning, $danger, $success, $info];


    @for (int i = 0 ; i < Model.ChartsList.Count; i++)
    {
        <text>
            var labelPie+@i+_Coverage =[];
            var seriesPie+@i+_Coverage = [];
            var arrayPie+@i+_Coverage = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.ChartsList[i].Analytic?.ToList()));


            for (j = 0; j & lt; arrayPie+@i+_Coverage?.length; j++) {

                labelPie+@i+_Coverage.push(arrayPie+@i+_Coverage[j].name);
                seriesPie+@i+_Coverage.push(arrayPie+@i+_Coverage[j].count);
            }

    var pieChart+@i+_Options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        height: 520
    },
    colors: themeColors,
        labels: labelPie+@i+_Coverage,
        series: seriesPie+@i+_Coverage,
    legend: {
        itemMargin: {
            horizontal: 2
        },
    },
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 576,
        options: {
            chart: {
                width: 300
            },
            legend: {
                position: 'bottom'
            }
        }
    }]
}
    var pie+@i+_Chart = new ApexCharts(
    document.querySelector("#pie-chart"+@i+"_Coverage"),
    pieChart+@i+_Options
);
pie+@i+_Chart.render();
</text>
        }
    </script>
```

I can't see any charts in the view.

Comment: It's kind of hard for us to test this, hence try to look at the source for a page with a working chart, then add just one chart to your collection and look for differences. BR

Comment: This is exactly what I did. It works fine when there is only one data. The problem is when I’m looping multiple charts. I know I’m doing something wrong, but don’t know what.

Comment: If you add the rendered script (from page source) to your question, I'll guess it will be more easy to see the error. BR